# Can anybody helps with this problem?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I have uses this repo https://github.com/rmeissner/safe-migrator.
I have just changed url of sdkService.

export const serviceUrl = "https://safe-transaction.bsc.gnosis.io/"

[image]

Comment: Help with personal projects is out of scope for stack exchange. Please create an issue in the repo and wait for a response from the maintainer.

Answer (score 2):

I think it needs that particular function in that url. The existing url must be using SDK logic. You need to deep dive what safe migration sdk is providing in the backend